# Why F10 doesn't working the second time?

Tags: c++, mfc

In my MFC application, the first time I press <kbd>F10</kbd>, the shortkey works. But for the subsequent press of <kbd>F10</kbd>, nothing happens. I saw using debug view that `pMsg->lParam` contains `0x440001` for the first time. From the second time onwards `pMsg->lParam` contains `0x10440001`.

Comment: Show us your code pls where you implement this

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>F10</kbd> is treated specially by Windows. When you press <kbd>F10</kbd>, the focus is put into the menu and then you can use the arrow keys to navigate through the menu. This behaviour dates back to Windows 3 (or even further). Your problem is probably related to this.

Open Notepad, press <kbd>F10</kbd> and then use the arrow keys, and you'll see what happens.

I've made a very simple MFC application (using Visual Studio 2010) and if I create a shortcut for the <kbd>F10</kbd> key, MFC seems to takes care of everything and the <kbd>F10</kbd> key fires up the command, so it's quite strange that it doesn't work in your MFC app. If I remove from the F10 from the accelerator, <kbd>F10</kbd> behaves again like in Notepad.

Try replacing the <kbd>F10</kbd> short cut by <kbd>F11</kbd> and look if the problem goes away. If not, the cause is probably unrelated.